# CR LF endline causes 500 error on Python script

Tags: python, linux, apache, python-3.x, shebang

I'm not sure if this is Apache, *nix, or Python, but for whatever reason, I'm getting a 500 error when I try to run a Python script on my remote server.

I develop in Windows, so all my line endings have the standard `CR LF` (\r\n) line endings. However, this seems to cause an issue: my error log gives this:

> [PYTHON PATH]/python: can't open file '\r': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I contacted support about this, with a simple file, and they responded telling me it now works. When I looked at the file, and the line endings, the only difference was that it just has the LF line ending now.

I realize I there is probably some way in Notepad++ to change the line endings, but that isn't a solution for me, as

- I don't want to go change every file to have the right line endings
- I might create a simple script in regular Notepad, which would have the standard CR LF endings, which would make things still crash
- I might be given a file from somebody else in a Windows environment, and I don't want to have to worry about updating their line endings.

Naturally, the scripts work perfectly on my locally installed server (XAMPP). How can I get the Python installed on my server to act the same way? Or Apache, or whatever is causing it?

FYI, using the latest version of Python (3.4.2). I don't know what type of *nix is installed, but it's a shared server, so changes are limited.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this has almost nothing with python itself. Unix line endings are single '\n', so extra '\r' is simply considered as an argument for the command line in the shebang.

Comment: Probably you could run you python script through a wrapper that would exclude extra '\r', but it seems that it would be wiser to simply strip off '\r' on deployment. How do you deploy your scripts to the server?

Comment: @user3159253, FileZilla or NppFTP usually.

Comment: Then simply transfer .py files using text mode. In FileZilla something like  "Menu -> Edit -> Settings -> Transfers -> File Types -> ..."

Comment: For the files with DOS line endings that are already on the Linux system you can quickly convert them in a variety of ways. You probably have [dos2unix](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) installed. But if not, it's easy enough to do with a short `sed` command, eg `sed -i.dos 's/\r//' filepattern` will convert all files matching filepattern. The `-i.dos`, option says to modify the files in-place and save the original files under the same names but with a `.dos` extension.

Comment: I ended up just converting all my files, and changing Notepad++. Not a solution, but a required work around I guess. I'll just have to be careful not to create anything in Notepad or IDLE.